# How to check if a key exists in Json Object and get its value

Tags: java, android, json, performance, android-layout

Let say this is my `JSON Object`

```
{
  "LabelData": {
    "slogan": "AWAKEN YOUR SENSES",
    "jobsearch": "JOB SEARCH",
    "contact": "CONTACT",
    "video": "ENCHANTING BEACHSCAPES",
    "createprofile": "CREATE PROFILE"
  }
}
```

I need to know that either 'video` exists or not in this Object, and if it exists i need to get the value of this key. I have tried following, but i am unable to get value of this key.

```
 containerObject= new JSONObject(container);
 if(containerObject.hasKey("video")){
  //get Value of video
}
```

Comment: which json library (name and version) are you using?

Comment: why dont you use gson library for parsing Json to Java Obj and vise versa

Comment: what is `container` here?

Comment: container is simple JsonObject. I am using simple JSONObject in android

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use below code to find key is exist or not in `JsonObject`. `has("key")` method is used to find keys in `JsonObject`.

```
containerObject = new JSONObject(container);
//has method
if (containerObject.has("video")) {
    //get Value of video
    String video = containerObject.optString("video");
}
```

If you are using `optString("key")` method to get String value then don't worry about keys are existing or not in the `JsonObject`.

Comment: Note that you can check only root keys with has(). Get values with get().

Comment: if you dont find the containerObject.has you can try containerObject.containsKey.. I did this..

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
if (containerObject.has("video")) {
    //get value of video
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
containerObject = new JSONObject(container);
if (containerObject.has("video")) { 
   //get Value of video
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the structure of your source Object, I would try:

```
containerObject= new JSONObject(container);
 if(containerObject.has("LabelData")){
  JSONObject innerObject = containerObject.getJSONObject("LabelData");
     if(innerObject.has("video")){
        //Do with video
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try this one..

```
JSONObject jsonObject= null;
try {
     jsonObject = new JSONObject("result........");
     String labelDataString=jsonObject.getString("LabelData");
     JSONObject labelDataJson= null;
     labelDataJson= new JSONObject(labelDataString);
     if(labelDataJson.has("video")&&labelDataJson.getString("video")!=null){
       String video=labelDataJson.getString("video");
     }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

JSONObject class has a method named "has".
Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
private boolean hasKey(JSONObject jsonObject, String key) {
    return jsonObject != null && jsonObject.has(key);
}

  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJson);
        if (hasKey(jsonObject, "labelData")) {
            JSONObject labelDataJson = jsonObject.getJSONObject("LabelData");
            if (hasKey(labelDataJson, "video")) {
                String video = labelDataJson.getString("video");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }
```

Comment: does this work for lists and nested lists in a json?

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject root= new JSONObject();
JSONObject container= root.getJSONObject("LabelData");

try{
//if key will not be available put it in the try catch block your program 
 will work without error 
String Video=container.getString("video");
}
catch(JsonException e){

 if key will not be there then this block will execute

 } 
 if(video!=null || !video.isEmpty){
  //get Value of video
}else{
  //other vise leave it
 }
```

i think this might help you

Comment: if key is not exist then your if conditions executes or not ?

Comment: Using Exception handling for such thing is very bad solution.